# Objective C unsharp mask filter Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter, photo, imaging

What would be the most efficient way to create an unsharp mask filter in Objective C targeting iOS? Would it be best to implement some open source like ImageMagick or build from scratch.

I think the basic formula is generally as follows (please comment if I have not gotten it right).

1. Duplicate original
2. Blur duplicate (Gaussian)
3. blend with original via "difference"
4. use result to mask original
5. Increase contrast in the unmasked areas of the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Image has the [CIUnsharpMask filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIUnsharpMask) built-in, although I'm not sure if it's available on iOS yet. Brad Larson's [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) also has an unsharp mask filter.

Both methods should be very fast and much easier to implement than cross-compiling ImageMagick or writing your own.

Comment: By the way, I think unsharp mask is not available in CoreImage for iOS yet. Here is a list I printed of core image filters for iOS:http://oliverwolfson.com/code/CoreImageFilters.txt

Comment: @Mrwolfy - Yes, none of the blur filters made it across from Core Image on the Mac to iOS. This was one of the reasons I wrote my framework. You can see my unsharp mask implementation by building and running the FilterShowcase sample application in the framework. It differs slightly from what you describe above in that I just mix the original and Gaussian blurred image colors using an intensity factor. This is the textbook implementation of an unsharp mask, and produces results that match those of common image editors. It's also fast enough to run on live video on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
(UIImage *)useOfUnsharpMask:(CIImage *)beginImage 
{

    float sliderValue = sharpnessSlider.value;
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIUnsharpMask" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey,beginImage,@"inputIntensity",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sliderValue],@"inputRadius",@2.50, nil];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];

    return finalImage;
}
```

Hope that helps :)